# Why $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field?

Tags: field-theory

I was reading this question (that has been changed a bit). By definition $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a ring. It's the ring $\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$.

**Q1)** Does $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ by definition or $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]\cong \{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ ?

**Q2)** why does $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ (where $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$) ?

Comment: Hint. For (2), rationalize the denominator of $1/(a+b\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: You wrote above "I was reading this question (that has been changed a bit)." What question is 'this'? Not the one your posing now?

Comment: @peterag : "Not the one your posing now? " what question is this ?

Comment: @surb - I was wondering whether there was a missing link to some other question.

Comment: A priori, it's not quite clear here what ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt 2]$ is, nor what is meant by $\sqrt 2$ - do you mean the subfield of the complexes, and the positive real number, the square of which is $2$?

Comment: @peter $\sqrt2$ is never ambiguous, and the notation $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2] $ is extremely standard.

Comment: @MattSamuel (as you know) there are two real numbers, the square of which is $2$, the positive being the popular choice. However, in the (p-adic) field of ${\mathbb Q}_7$ (of char. zero), there are (also) two numbers, equally popular, with squares equal to $2$ - hence one can imbed '${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt 2]$' in two different ways in   ${\mathbb Q}_7$.  So what's  '${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt 2]$'? (As you know) one can define  '${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt 2]$ "canonically" as  '${\mathbb Q}[x] / (x^2-2)'$... (cont)

Comment: @MattSamuel (cont) I agree the OP (probably/no doubt) meant what you meant, but I was trying to ask where the question was coming from. As it is, (to number theoretic eyes, say) the question is a little bit ill-posed - and Galois (cough) might disagree with your "never ambiguous" - if he weren't dead, that is.

Comment: @peter It's never ambiguous over the reals. It means the positive real number whose square is $2$.

Comment: @MattSamuel eppur si muove, but yes. Of course,  had the original question been about ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt {-1}]$...

Answer (score 4):

This is one point where rationalizing the denominator is important, even though it wasn't in grade school.
$$\frac1{a+b\sqrt 2}=\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2}$$
Since $\sqrt2$ is irrational, $a^2-2b^2\neq 0$ as long as either $a$ or $b$ is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

Other than computations to find the inverse of any $a+b\sqrt 2\ne0$, you can observe that it is a finite dimensional $\mathbf Q$-vector space, and multiplication by $a+b\sqrt 2$ is an *injective* $\mathbf Q$-linear map, hence it is bijective. In particular, $1$ is attained, i.e. there exists $c+d\sqrt 2$ such that
$$(a+b\sqrt 2)(c+d\sqrt 2)=1.$$

Comment: Ok, but does $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ or $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]\cong\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ ?

Comment: @user657324 Both.

Answer (score 2):

Q1) The second one !

Q2) Because $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field. If $a+b\sqrt 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, you can easily find $c+d\sqrt 2$ s.t. $(a+b\sqrt 2)(c+d\sqrt 2)=1$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field because $\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic number i.e. it is the solution of a polynomial with rational coefficients, namely $x^2=2$. This means, for example, that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$.

On the other hand $\mathbb Q[\pi]$ is not a field because $\pi$ is transcendental, so $\frac{1}{\pi} \notin \mathbb Q[\pi]$.